# AWS RDS: How to Connect

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

Here is what I'm trying to do..

I'm trying to connect to an AWS RDS instance using an front end tool like Heidi SQL or whatever is out there.

I put in the hostname: xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
The user: User Name
The Password: Password

Then in SSH Tunnel, I would put in the following information:
Plink location
SSH Host + Port xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
The Username: User name
The password  Password

Private key: key.ppk
and I have the local port at 22.

But I'm getting a Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).

Is there anyway I can get around this error so I can access the database.

Thank you..

Comment: Local port 22 seems like an odd choice.

Answer (score -4):

Never mind, I found a solution. I found a way to access the RDS and found a solution.

Comment: You should provide details of this solution so other people who find your question in the future can benefit from it.